# Trying to trigger an ASP Button generated in a gridview after hitting enter in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that generates several rows each row contains a couple of dynamically created text boxes and 2 buttons.  When UpdateBtn1 is clicked the DB is updated with the values from the textboxes.  Ultimately the user should have the ability to either click the update button or hit enter when using either of the textboxes to trigger the update.

Here is where I am at at this point.

```
<asp:GridView ID="InitialData" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowDataBound="gv_GridDataBound"
                OnRowCommand="InitialRowButton_Click"
                DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="InitialData_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="UpdateBtn1" ButtonType="Button" Text="Update" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CommandName="Run_Update" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Input Textbox1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="RequestBtn" CommandName="Get_Weight" HeaderText="Request Weight"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" runat="server" Text="Request Weight" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="InputText1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MEASURED_WEIGHT") %>' Width="50px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpWeightBox"
                                ControlToValidate="InputText1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Illegal"
                                ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,5}$" class="regExpress">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="STATUSDDL" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Input Textbox2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="InputTextbox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200" Rows="2" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

I have attempted to use the onclick event to both trigger the button or to trigger a javascript function that would trigger the button.  In both cases i couldnt isolate the button on the same row as the textboxes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a solution to my dilemma.

What i ended up doing was adding an atribute to the ondatabound method to call a javascript function.  I get the button Id by finding the control for each and passing it into the attribute.  Here is the C#

```
protected void gv_GridDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Button b_l_updateButton = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateBtn1");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", String.Format("RunUpdate(event,'{0}');", b_l_updateButton.ClientID));
}
```

Here is the javascript

```
function RunUpdate(e, UpdateButtonID) {
        var keynum

        if (window.event) 
        {
            keynum = e.keyCode
        }
        else if (e.which) 
        {
            keynum = e.which
        }
        if (keynum == 13) {
            document.getElementById(UpdateButtonID).click();
        }
    }
```